# How to count number of digit in decimal numbers using PHP

Tags: php, count, numbers, counting

I am working to count number of digit in PHP. Before decimal place integer I want to count number of digit 
**for example:**

```
123.456  ==number of count value is 3 
1.234 ==number of count value is 1 
12.1  ==number of count value is 2
```

Let me know how to solve it.

Comment: please accept one of the answers below

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
strlen((int)23.23);
```

output:

```
2
```

Comment: Or strpos(num,'.')

Answer (score 2):

You can also do something like this:

```
strlen(explode('.', 9.9)[0])
```

Which would yield 1